# How to get units of a keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I get the units (i.e. the number of neurons) of a layer in Keras?

For example:

```
layer = keras.layers.Dense(5)
print(layer.units)
```

would print `5`, but

```
layer = keras.layers.InputLayer(5)
print(layer.units)
```

would throw an error.

Is there a universal way to grab the units count of a Keras layer?

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma [There is, actually](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer), at least under `tf.keras.layers`.

Comment: I don't think `units` is a property that necessarily applies to every kind of layer. If you want to know the shape of the output of each layer, you can use `.output_shape`. If you are interested in the total number of parameters, there is `.count_params()`.

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma Meant `keras.layers.InputLayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using model.summary(). It is a pretty useful function and would show a lot of things like the shapes of each layer, what algorithm is being used etc..

It also shows the input layers.

Here is an example of what the output looks like:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
user_id (InputLayer)            (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
movie_id (InputLayer)           (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
user_embedding (Embedding)      (None, 1, 8)         8000        user_id[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
movie_embedding (Embedding)     (None, 1, 8)         8000        movie_id[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 1, 16)        0           user_embedding[0][0]             
                                                                 movie_embedding[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 16)           0           concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1)            17          flatten[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,017
Trainable params: 16,017
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

(Edit) As per tomerg45's request, I am explaining what output shapes are

In CNNs we add what is called a kernel. It is used to extract the various important parts of an image and resize it to decrease time and computation power. There are multiple layers in a model that do this such as conv2D, maxpool2D etc.

Output shapes are the final shapes you receive after the layers have been applied. These are always supposed to be converted into 1D. This can be done using flatten in Keras.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I knew about that function already but I now see that what I was looking for is the output shape, if you can add an explanation on what it is and how to get I’ll set it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong here. Lets start by seeing what `units` of a dense layer mean. It specifies the output dimensionality or in other words the number of neurons inside the Dense layer (since a single neuron outputs a single value).

However `InputLayer` is a layer to accepts the inputs. It is not a layer with weights but just passes on the inputs it gets to the next layers. So it does not have any neurons and so it does not have `units`.

In then case you are looking a way to find `units` if it has then you can use code like below:

```
layer = keras.layers.InputLayer(5)
i = layer.nunits if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Dense) else 0
layer = keras.layers.Dense(5)
j = layer.units if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.Dense) else 0

print (i, j)
```

Output:

```
0 5
```

Or for any layer

```
layer = keras.layers.InputLayer(5)
i = layer.nunits if hasattr(layer, 'units') else 0
layer = keras.layers.Dense(5)
j = layer.units if hasattr(layer, 'units') else 0

print (i, j)
```